# Replacing single placeholder only using cursor.execute()

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, tuples, psycopg2

As an example, if i have the following code:

```
sql = """ select  r.id,
            format('DATA "(%s)"',
            replace(replace(sql,'<<','%'),'>>','%')) as data,
            rcode,
            format('  VALIDATION
            ''userid'' ''^\d+$''%s END',
            string_agg(format ('    ''%s'' ''%s''', paramname,prompt[1]),' ')) as validation
FROM report.reports r
JOIN report.reportparams rp on r.id = rp.reportid and not rp.del
where r.id = %s
group by r.id, sql, rcode;"""
```

The FIRST FOUR `%s` placeholders are replaced by the database.
The LAST `%s` is the only variable that needs to be passed by this code.

That `%s` needs to become the variable report_id which is specified previously in the code.

My initial thought was to replace the last `%s' with report_id in the sql variable such that the line of code would now look like:

`where r.id = report_id`

except that gives me an error saying that the variable report_id does not exist.

the next line of code after the sql variable is:

`cursor.execute(sql)`

if i manually change the sql section so that the last `%s` is an actual number (like its supposed to be), the code executes.

How do I run the cursor.execute() line such that the last `%s` is substituted by the variable report_id while the first 4 `%s` are left to be replaced by the database.

NOTE: I have tried replacing the first 4 `%s` with another `%s` by running the following:

`cursor.execute(sql,(%s,%s,%s,%s,report_id))`

but that doesn't work for hopefully obvious reasons. it gives me the invalid syntax error

and also, if i change the line to:

`cursor.execute(sql,('%s','%s','%s','%s',report_id))`

it gives me a tuple index out of range error which brings me back to square one where i started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use format() and make the final `%s` a `{}` then you can keep the first four `%s` as they are and only format the last one.

```
sql = """[sql stuff and %s]{}""".format(report_id)
```

It will leave all the `%s`'s alone, but I can't guarantee it will solve any problem beyond that.